window.open() returns a window object but doesn't open a new window
I am trying to develop a feature that relies on having 2 screens and from a window in screen A I try to open window in screen B. using
window.open(URL, "_blank", "left=ScreenA.width, top=0,width=ScreenB.width,height=ScreenB.height")

I am aware that doing this will require two permissions window-management & pop-ups & redirects
I gave both of these permissions.
I was trying it on Chromebox version 125 and it worked like charm.
When I was trying it on Chrome OS version 114. window.open(...) was returning a Window object but nothing opens.
I expected both to return Window object and actually opens the window.
I need to know why? does this feature rely on specific chrome version?

Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

No error shows and as I mentioned window.open(...) returns object.

Do you really have left=ScreenA.width in the features string? I didn't know you could put expressions like that in there.
